# CSS3 Firefox filter grayscale without blur effect matrix

Tags: css, firefox, filter

What i have now is the following code to grayscale my image (found here on stackoverflow). Problem is this also blurres the image. I would like a matrix that only adjusts the color to grayscale, and not changing the blurriness of my picture.

CSS Code:

```
filter: url(svg/filters.svg#grayscale);
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing with the [`filterRes`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterResAttribute) attribute, it defines the

> width and height of the intermediate images in pixels

and can have an drastic impact on the image quality. See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jxtjt/

```
<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png'>

img {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='grayscale' filterRes='600'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}
img:hover {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='grayscale' ><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}
```

The original filter uses an `filterRes` setting of `600` pixels, which looks ok at least on *my* display, it may look different on other displays, maybe especially on HI-DPI ones. Hover over the image to see the filter being applied without the `filterRes` attribute being set.

Depending on your use case this might be a workaround for you.

To me this looks like a bug in Firefox (you may want to file a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)). According to the specs, the user-agent is responsible for calculating values that look good on the output device in case they weren't set, so maybe that's where Firefox goes wrong, not sure.