# Cross-browser image CSS filter

Tags: css, firefox, svg, filter, cross-browser

I have problem with image filter in FireFox.
I have this code:

`-webkit-filter: grayscale(0.5) sepia(0.3);`

It works in Chrome and in Opera

I neet that it works in FF and other popular browsers.

I found this:

`filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");`

but I do not anderstand how it works.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I think this answer can help you.


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517306/css3-firefox-filter-grayscale-without-blur-effect-matrix

Comment: no, it's didn't help...I need 50% of grayscale and 30% of sepia. But in that link example is only blur effect. I don't need that. But thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the [draft filters spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#grayscaleEquivalent) to see what the SVG filter equivalents of those CSS filters are.

Comment: That is helping, but it is usefull only for greyscale: `filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.6063 0.3576 0.0361 0 0 0.1063 0.8576 0.0361 0 0 0.1063 0.3576 0.5361 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");`  and is not use for sepia: `filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'sepia\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.8179 0.2307 0.0567 0 0 0.1047 0.9058 0.0504 0 0 0.0816 0.1602 0.7393 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#sepia");`

Comment: and I do not know how to use it both

Answer (score 0):

I found answer on this site. And with helping by [Michael Mullany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271353/michael-mullany).

`.element {
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'old-timey\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.8179 0.2307 0.0567 0 0 0.1047 0.9058 0.0504 0 0 0.0816 0.1602 0.7393 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#old-timey");
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.6063 0.3576 0.0361 0 0 0.1063 0.8576 0.0361 0 0 0.1063 0.3576 0.5361 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}`
It works with FireFox and div background-image in CSS